# Error while installing WWW::Selenium through CPAN

Tags: perl, selenium, activeperl

I have installed ActivePerl PPM and Strawberry Perl(Padre). Tried installing WWW::Selenium CPAN from command prompt through

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install WWW::Selenium
```

It throws the following error

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/test_default_server.t (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 7 tests but ran 1.
Files=12, Tests=344, 31 wallclock secs ( 0.14 usr +  0.06 sys =  0.20 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/12 test programs. 1/344 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
  MATTP/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.36.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports MATTP/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.36.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 MATTP/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.36.tar.gz          : make_test NO
```

Also I have installed Selenium stand alone server (a jar file). But the following code doesn't work in command prompt.

```
java -jar <path of the selenium server>
```

P.S: I don't know Perl. I'm a beginner.

Comment: For the benefit of those who come after you and are trying to resolve the same problem, how did you fix it?